# Disable DB Updates in Spring boot JPA when changing the value of a property after it is fetched from the repository using findall or other queries

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am having a service that gets the data from the database which has a column which is stored with encrypted value.

After fetching from the DAO, i will update the value of the property to decrypted value and then send it as response for the API.

I assume that the entity is having change tracking enabled for select queries also because after i get the data, the data is updated in the DB with the decrypted password. I have googled and found that the use of `EntityManager` solves the problem, but for this implementation I have to do a lot of code changes in many entities.

from this link, i see that we have to write custom stateless bean and inject to the code, but it looks like not right. Please suggest me the best approach to handle this problem.

My DAO:

```
@Repository
public interface EnvironmentDao extends JpaRepository<Environment, Long> {
```

//custom methods go here with native queries
    }

My Service

```
@Override
    public List<Environment> getEnvironmentsByIds(List<Long> environmentIds) throws Exception {
        if (environmentIds == null || environmentIds.size() < 1) {
            return null;
        }

        return decryptPassword(environmentDao.findAllById(environmentIds));
    }
```

Inside the decryptPassword method, i am just looping through all the records and then setting the decrypted password like

```
e.setDB_Password(encryptionService.decrypt(e.getDB_Password()));
```

One case that i noticed yesterday is that for a similar entity on any error, there was a DB save and that time the values got updated, so after fixing the error, this change was not happening.

Please help me as I am not an expert in java and taking more time to analyze and could not understand. In the case of C#, i would use `.AsNoTracking()`, but i don't know java much and fiddling around.

**Tried the following in the Service**

```
@Autowired
EntityManager entityManager;
```

In the method,

```
Optional<Environment> environment = environmentDao.findById(id);
entityManager.detach(environment.get());
return managePassword(environment.get(), false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest two options to overcome the entity being updated unintentionally:

1. Instead of returning the entity itself I would suggest creating a DTO class and creating an instance of that class and setting relevant properties on to the DTO instance so that no changes will be made to the entity itself. So the code will be sth like:

```
public List<EnvironmentDTO> getEnvironmentsByIds(List<Long> environmentIds) throws Exception {
  if (environmentIds == null || environmentIds.size() < 1) {
      return null;
  }

  return createEnvironmentDTOs(environmentDao.findAllById(environmentIds));
}

private LisT<EnvironmentDTO> createEnvironmentDTOs(List<Environment> environments) {
  return environments.stream().map((env) -> {
    EnvironmentDTO envDto = new EnvironmentDTO();
    // Copy all relevant fields to DTO (you can even use some Mapper library for this, i.e. http://modelmapper.org/)
    envDto.setDB_Password(encryptionService.decrypt(e.getDB_Password()));
  })
}
```

2. If you want to return the entity no matter what instead of creating a DTO class and instance from it; you can detach the entity so that changes to the entity will not be reflected to database. So what you need to do is [detaching](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach-java.lang.Object-) entity after you are done with decrypting the password and setting it back to the entity: `entityManager.detach(environment)`

Comment: I came across the `entityManager.detach(...)`, but i should have to rewrite all my service layer itself, which is too coslty. Also i can use a `clone` rather than doing a DTO transformation

Comment: if you can use `clone` please use it; but you have to implement the `clone` method if it is not there.

I do not get why you have to write all the service layer if you are to use `detach`. Add a new method to your service and call your existing method within the same service. then just before returning the object, perform a detach. this should work!

Comment: Currently, i am using `@Transactional(readonly=true)`, let me see how best it works out.

Comment: check out the following: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#readOnly--

readonly setting does not guarantee it will be readonly.

Comment: If i am having to detach, i should use EntityManager, i should perform all the queries through the entitymanager to detach it, otherwise how will it know which entities are attached and which ones are detached, can you please help me understand this aspect. I assume that we have to use either the `JPARepository` or use the `EntityManager`. or if i just inject the entity manager and call detach, will this be enough for this problem.

Comment: `JPARepostitory` instances should also be using `EntityManager` under the hood. Hence, you do not need to change anything in fetching your data from database. Just call `entityManager.detach(entity)`. It will be fine.

Comment: not working, this approach still saves my decrypted password to the database. not sure why JPA is such a painful library.

Comment: any chance you can share your full code; this does not seem correct in no way.

Comment: I have updated the code in the question, can you please check